# CiviCRM Mailing Question

Tags: mailing

My organization sent out a mailing to over 422 people. It only sent to 100 of the 422. Instead of it saying complete it says it is "running" which makes me think it will send more, but it's been over 24 hours and it has still only sent 100 of them on the dot. Not sure what to do here? Last time we sent a mailing it sent to 376 people and we had 100% success rate on all the deliveries.

Comment: Which SMTP are you using? Did you check mailing report for number for recipient count?